# Laravel ЧПУ. Нужены идеи алгоритма

Tags: php, laravel

Ссылка:

```
'<a href="' . route('objectEditForm', ['object' => $object->url]) . '"  class="badge badge-success" title="Редагувати"><i class="fal fa-edit"></i></a>'
```

Роут:

```
Route::get('/edit/{object}', 'ObjectController@editFormShow')->name('objectEditForm');
```

Ну и пока что пустой контроллер:

```
public function editFormShow(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->input('object'));
    }
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы доставать не по ИД объект - а по url. Как бы это сделать? 
Вариант с разбитием ссылки на массив и после этого достать по значению не подходит, так как url может потом быть как по центру так и в конце. Подкиньте идею господа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в нужную модель метод

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

где `slug` - нужное поле модели, по которому роутер будет ее искать

Comment: Спасибо, не знал об этом, а  если мне нужно будет обратно по ИД?

Comment: Подскажите еще, а как передать этот же объект только уже в middleware?

Comment: @AlexandrRevnuk если нужно по id, можно вернуть значение `id` или просто убрать метод из модели. Про middleware не скажу точно, вроде бы нельзя забиндить модель в мидлвейр без танцев с бубнами. Но можно получить в middleware параметр из роута и сделать запрос к БД, чтобы получить модель

Comment: А как получить параметр? Я видел что через : передавать в мидлваре, но я не знаю как получить этот url из ссылки